# No edit and continue for C# Docker Console App?

Tags: c#, docker, debugging

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 to create a .Net Core Console application. I want to host this application as a Docker container (for Linux). As soon as I add the Docker support to the project, Visual Studio will run the debug within Docker, which I guess is nice since I can make sure the application behaves similar to production.

However, when debugging this way, i loose the ability to do edit/continue and basic debugging capabilities such as "Set next statement". Is there some way to get these capabilities for a Docker console app, or alternatively run the console app as a normal .Net core app while developing and only switch to Docker for some final testing?